# Sending PDF file from webserver (php) to client PC for printing

Tags: php, pdf, printing, webserver

I have sushi online webshop, when orders are made i would like to have a PDF file sendt from the webserver to a computer in the restaurant that automaticly prints the document.

Today i use dropbox to achive this and a script on the restaurant computer to scan the dropboxfolder for new documents. This works, but if there are problems with the dropbox service it breaks, and the sniffing script is a bit unreliable (sometimes prints multiple copies).

The perfect solution would be a small client program/prosess that runs on the restaurant computer and can receive the PDF file from the webserver and print it.

Is there any easy way to achive this?

Comment: Can't you just browse to the PDF files on the webserver?

Comment: I need the PDF (receipt) to be printed automaticly on the printer in the restaurant without any human interaction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google offers [Cloudprint](https://developers.google.com/cloud-print/); allowing you to directly connect to your printer (via or without your restaurant computer, depending on the type of printer). They have some code online available demonstrating the available options to write software that connects to Cloudprinter.

Comment: This sounds very much like what I am looking for, going to take a look at it, thank you very much!